# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Battery stuck on 'estimating'

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, lts, bug-reporting

I recently installed Ubuntu (today, actually!) from Windows 10 and I've been loving it so far. I'm currently on an HP Spectre x360 and the battery's status is stuck on "Estimating..". Occasionally it would give me the correct percentage after waiting for a long period of time or when charging. Is there anything I can do?

Update: Opening Power Statistics has 'forced' the Estimating status to go away and now displays the power. Why is this?

Comment: See if the problem still occurs in a 19.10 LiveUSB. If so, report the bug. If not, the bug was fixed sometime in the last two years.

Comment: @user535733 the bug was fixed two years ago? I have tried looking at other posts but I don't see any solutions for it

Comment: Re-read my comment carefully.

Comment: your lucky - opening power statistics shows me the charge level (it's "stuck" at 89% since i have it set in the BIOS to not charge about 90% to save battery life) but the "estimating" NEVER goes away.